# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L\ \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ 3f(2x) \right] = 3L$.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this question.

My (rough) work so far:

Since we can assume $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$, we can conclude that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, even $\frac{1}{3} \varepsilon$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $0 < \lvert 2x \rvert < \delta\ \Rightarrow\ \lvert f(2x) - L \rvert < \frac{1}{3} \varepsilon$.

Since $\vert f(2x) - L \rvert < \frac{1}{3} \varepsilon$, it follows that $\lvert 3f(2x) - 3L \rvert < \varepsilon$, which implies $\lim_{x \to 0} \left[ 3f(2x) \right] = 3L$, as required.

I don't quite understand how this should be done; any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\quad\exists \delta>0\quad \forall x\quad |x|<\delta \quad|3f(2x)-3L|=3|f(2x)-L|<\epsilon \iff |f(2x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}3$$

then since $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$

$$\forall \epsilon_1>0 \quad\exists \delta_1>0\quad \forall x\quad |x|<\delta_1 \quad |f(x)-L|<\epsilon_1 $$

and it suffices to take $\epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon}3$ and $\delta=\frac{\delta_1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just to clarify, at the end where you state what values will work: are those subscripts where they should be?

Comment: @Euler'sFriend Assuming $\epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon}3$ we find $\delta_1$ such that $$\forall x\quad |x|<\delta_1 \quad |f(x)-L|<\epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon}3$$ and therefore $$\forall x\quad |x|<\frac{\delta_1}2 \quad |f(2x)-L|<\epsilon_1=\frac{\epsilon}3$$